# How to redirect npgsql log output to a log4net logger?

Tags: logging, log4net, npgsql

Is it possible to redirect the npgsql log output to go to a log4net logger? From the npgsql source code, it looks like it logs directly to stdout/stderr or a specified file (using the static properties on `NpgsqlEventLog`). Is there a way to route that logging into log4net?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I have done it and it seems to work reasonably well. Note that I am splitting the command logging out to a separate appender because it gets pretty verbose...

First, add this before you make any other calls to Npgsql:

```cs
NpgsqlLogManager.Provider = new Log4NetNpgsqlLoggingProvider("NpgsqlDefaultLogger")
{
    CommandLoggerName = "NpgsqlCommandLogger"
};
```

Now you need to add in the logging provider class:

```cs
using System;
using Npgsql.Logging;

namespace Util.Npgsql
{
    public class Log4NetNpgsqlLoggingProvider : INpgsqlLoggingProvider
    {
        public string DefaultLoggerName { get; }
        public string CommandLoggerName { get; set; }

        public Log4NetNpgsqlLoggingProvider(string defaultLoggerName)
        {
            if (defaultLoggerName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(defaultLoggerName));
            DefaultLoggerName = defaultLoggerName;
        }

        public NpgsqlLogger CreateLogger(string name)
        {
            switch (name)
            {
                case "Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand":
                    return new Log4NetNpgsqlLogger(CommandLoggerName ?? DefaultLoggerName);
                default:
                    return new Log4NetNpgsqlLogger(DefaultLoggerName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you also need the actual logger class:

```cs
using System;
using log4net;
using log4net.Core;
using Npgsql.Logging;

namespace Util.Npgsql
{
    public class Log4NetNpgsqlLogger : NpgsqlLogger
    {
        private readonly ILog _log;

        public Log4NetNpgsqlLogger(string name)
        {
            _log = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
        }

        public override bool IsEnabled(NpgsqlLogLevel level)
        {
            return _log.Logger.IsEnabledFor(GetLog4NetLevelFromNpgsqlLogLevel(level));
        }

        public override void Log(NpgsqlLogLevel level, int connectorId, string msg, Exception exception = null)
        {
            _log.Logger.Log(typeof(NpgsqlLogger), GetLog4NetLevelFromNpgsqlLogLevel(level), connectorId + ": " + msg, exception);
        }

        protected Level GetLog4NetLevelFromNpgsqlLogLevel(NpgsqlLogLevel level)
        {
            switch (level)
            {
                case NpgsqlLogLevel.Trace:
                case NpgsqlLogLevel.Debug:
                    return Level.Debug;
                case NpgsqlLogLevel.Info:
                    return Level.Info;
                case NpgsqlLogLevel.Warn:
                    return Level.Warn;
                case NpgsqlLogLevel.Error:
                    return Level.Error;
                case NpgsqlLogLevel.Fatal:
                    return Level.Fatal;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unknown Npgsql Log Level: " + level);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that in Npgsql 3.2.0: "Npgsql's custom logging has been replaced with [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging]". However, in 3.2.2 it was reverted: "Due to the many complaints, Npgsql 3.2's use of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging has been dropped, and logging now works as it did in Npgsql 3.1". refs: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases

Answer (score 0):

First add log4net to your solution, the easy way is to use nuget:
so you do this:
install-Package log4net
then you have to install npgsql:
install-Package npgsql

in your web.config file you add this elements: (you have to use app.config for not web solution)

At the configSection 
     printf("%d\n", 42);  /*

```
//the most important thing is to ensure that the type on your parameter         //section is correct. otherwise, no error will be returned, and no data will be         inserted.

//now, at your code you can use this function:

        protected void LogInfo(string message, params object[] args)
        {
            log4net.ILog log =     log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("postgreSqlLogAppender");
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["UserId"] = args.[0];
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["EntityId"] = args.[1];
            log.Info(string.Format("{0}: {1}",     this.GetType().Name.Replace("Controller", ""), string.Format(message, args)));
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties.Remove("UserId");
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties.Remove("EntityId");
        }


//to call your function
    void test()
{
   LogInfo("My message",15,326)
}


//in my case 15 is my current user_id and 326 is the my class_object.
     */
```

Comment: Doesn't address the OP's request, which was to be able to send npgsql's log output to log4net.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know anything about npgsql, but if you have the source and are allowed to change it,  then it **should** be easier to change it to support log4net.

If you didn't have the source, then it would not be easy and may not even be possible. Since log4net doesn't intercept output from other sources, the only way I could see of doing it would be to have a background thread that monitored the file that npgsql is outputing to, and when the file changes , you would need to read that file and parse the information and then call log4net with that information.

You still have the issue that log4net will think every call is coming from your routine and not npgsql and stack traces get messed up. Also would only work if npgsql was locking, opening, writing, and closing the file each time a log entry was made.